# Update one of 2 duplicates in an sql server database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a table that got a column with duplicate values. I would like to update one of a 2 duplicate values so for example `row1 = tom` and `row2 = tom`.. I want to add a 1 or an a to one of them and that will be for many other duplicates in the same column. Basically just add one number or letter to every 1 of the duplicates so there's no more duplicates.

I got this query that will update all the duplicates but not one of them. Can anyone help?

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET Column1 = 'a'
 WHERE exists
       (SELECT Column1 , COUNT(Column1 )
FROM Clients
GROUP BY Column1 
HAVING ( COUNT(Column1 ) > 1)
)
```

Comment: If its a duplicate record why do you need to keep it? is there a specific reason for doing so?

Comment: What does your schema look like? Any primary key to work with?

Comment: I need it because it's valuable information I don't want to delete any of them. Just want to distinguish them for data analysis purposes. Yes I got an ID which is a primary key.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try This with `CTE` and  `PARTITION BY`

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1  ORDER BY Column1 ) AS rno,
      Column1 
  FROM Clients
)

UPDATE cte SET Column1 =Column1 +' 1 '
WHERE rno=2
```

Comment: Don't you want to update the Clients table rather than "cte" (which is just a temporary thing)?  PostgreSQL rejected that syntax.  I ended up with something more like:
UPDATE Clients SET Column1 = Column1 + ' 1 ' WHERE cte.rno = 2;

Answer (score 16):

I think this simple update is what you're looking for;

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column1=Column1+CAST(id AS VARCHAR)
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(id) 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Column1
);
```

Input:

```
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'A'),
(4,'C'),
(5,'C'),
(6,'A');
```

Output:

```
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'A3'),
(4,'C'),
(5,'C5'),
(6,'A6');
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f7b7/1).

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use TOP() operator instead of row_number() method it  will help you to update one in easy and simple way

```
UPDATE TOP ( 1 )Table1 SET Column1 = 'a';
```

Comment: Please be sure of your answers.  Usually "I think" in an answer will make your answer less likely to be chosen.

Comment: This is the best answer.  It uses the correct tool from the application and it's not a workaround. (Also, it works - it just solved the problem I had.)

Comment: It worked for me. This was the simplest solution. In oracle you can use rowid (a unique number oracle gives for each row) to identify each row distinctly.

Answer (score 5):

If we have this condition:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Clients ORDER BY Column1

Column1
**********
Jhon
Jhon
Mike
Mike
Mike
Robert
```

This will work even if `Column1` was duplicated n times, it will append the row number to every duplicate row except the first, try this:

```
BEGIN 

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column1) AS ROWNUMBER,
        Column1
    FROM Clients
)

UPDATE CTE 
SET Column1 = CONCAT(Column1, ' ', (ROWNUMBER - 1))
WHERE ROWNUMBER > 1

SELECT Column1 FROM Clients ORDER BY Column1

END
```

Result:

```
Column1
***********
Jhon
Jhon 1
Mike
Mike 1
Mike 2
Robert
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume `Table1`, containing the following information:

```
Column1      
========  
tom        
john   
jack    
tom     
james
jane
```

Notice that the first and fourth rows are identical. Here's the `UPDATE` command to change the name in only one of them.

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t1
   SET Column1 = 'jennifer'
 WHERE rrn(t1) =
       (SELECT MAX(rrn(t2))
          FROM Table1 AS t2
         WHERE Column1 = 'tom')
```

And the result would be

```
Column1      
========  
tom        
john   
jack    
jennifer
james
jane
```

with `RRN` function you can update the last occurance of duplicate record

Comment: This will change any tom to a which i don't want. I got a big data and that column got many duplicates. All I want is to add a letter or incremented number at the end of one of the duplicates rather than doing it manually.

Comment: It is refusing to accept the AS t1 after the update.. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this mate

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Column1 = column1 +'a'   
WHERE exists(
        select row 
        from (
            SELECT 
                Column1 , 
                Row_Number() over(Partition by Column1 order by Column1) as row 
            FROM Clients
        ) as subquery 
        where subquery.row = 2
    )
```

Comment: Its Updating all rows. I mean all Duplicate rows

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
with test as 
(
   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by salary)rr, salary , emp_no 
   from salary
)update test set emp_no=10007 where emp_no='10002'  and rr=3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the with inside a from since my sql developer didnt like updating a with
Copying from the answer from Nithesh

it ended up looking like this:

```
UPDATE Clients 
SET Column1 = 'a'
WHERE ColumnID IN (select ColumnID from 
 (  
 SELECT
       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1  ORDER BY Column1 ) AS rno,
       ColumnID FROM Clients
 )
                   where rno=2   
                  )
```

Comment: this sets all to null

Answer (score 0):

Using sub-queries might work:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET STATUS = 'F'
WHERE column1= 
   (SELECT (column1)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY column1 
    HAVING (COUNT(column1 ) > 1))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide some explanation for how this solves the asker's problem, so that future users can learn from your answer.

Comment: SQL Error [90150] [22000]: Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
update wmwhse1.sku
set descr= concat (descr,'.')
where exists
(select SKU,count (DESCR)
from wmwhse1.sku
group by descr
having (count (DESCR)>1))
```

all sku description is updating when I run this script.

output: only 1 row should be affected

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution:

My table *devices* already have data and the "serial" column should be unique. The "id" is a primary key. A random 6 digits value is concatenated after the original value.

```
UPDATE devices 
SET serial=CONCAT(serial,'_',LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 6, '0'))    
    where id in 
    (select * FROM( 
        SELECT d1.id as id 
        FROM devices as d1, devices as d2 
        WHERE d1.id <> d2.id and d1.serial=d2.serial) as subdevices
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:

1. Query Language: Microsoft SQL Query
2. Steps are clarified in comments like : --

Question: UPDATE last Id with 'D' where year, month is duplicate memberwise.

```
-- Sample Table Creation

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
( Id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, MemberId INT, for_year INT, for_month INT, for_status CHAR(1) )

-- Sample Insert
INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT '2', '2077', '11', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '2077', '12', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '2077', '12', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '2077', '11', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '2077', '12', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '2077', '12', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '77', '2076', '10', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '77', '2076', '11', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT '77', '2076', '12', 'A'

-- logic to update
UPDATE @TempTable SET for_status = 'D' WHERE Id IN 
(
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @TempTable GROUP BY MemberId, for_year, for_month HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)

-- Sample Select
SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

I have found one solution:

Insert a dummy column in the table

Update the values in column and give random value

Update the row using that dummy column's value and drop the column.

```
Step 1 :
Alter table table_name
ADD column dummy_column

Step 2:
Update table_name
SET dummy_column = (RAND() * 10) 
where duplicate_column = duplicate_value

Step 3:
Update table_name
SET duplicate_column = new_value
where dummy_column = random_value

Step 4:
Alter table table_name
drop column dummy_column
```