# SQL Update first occurence of duplicate

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, duplicates

I have a DB which is populated from a utility which did not handle simultaneous requests well.

The logic for inserting the rows in these tables was flawed which allowed for duplicates in the derived table. My aim is to fix those duplicates.

There are two types of duplicates that have come up:

1. Where the Key is a duplicate, but we can use the Number to tell them
   apart
2. Where the Key and Number are both duplicates, in this case I
   want to update the first occurrence.

Here is how the situation has come up

```
/** Sequence of events **/


/** First Set (Correct) **/

Insert into Base values(100,'Base1');
    /** Find the biggest IKey in Base Table **/
    /** Set that as IKey in Derived Table (IKey = 1)**/
Insert into Derived values(1,100,'Derived1');

Insert into Base values(101,'Base2');
    /** Find the biggest IKey in Base Table **/
    /** Set that as IKey in Derived Table (IKey = 2)**/
Insert into Derived values(2,101,'Derived2');



/** Second Set ( duplicate IKey )**/

Insert into Base values(200,'Base3');
    /** Find the biggest IKey in Base Table **/
    /** We would have gotten 3, but there was another insert before this query could be run **/
Insert into Base values(201,'Base4');
    /** Because of the insert, we got a 4 instead of a 3 **/


    /** Set that as IKey in Derived Table (IKey = 4)**/
Insert into Derived values(4,200,'Derived3');
    /** Find the biggest IKey in Base Table **/
    /** Set that as IKey in Derived Table (IKey = 4)**/
Insert into Derived values(4,201,'Derived4');




/** Third Set ( duplicate IKey and Number )**/

Insert into Base values(300,'Base5');
    /** Find the biggest IKey in Base Table **/
    /** We would have gotten 5, but there was another insert before this query could be run **/
    /** This even had the "Number" column same as previous insert **/ 

Insert into Base values(300,'Base6');
    /** Because of the insert, we got a 6 instead of a 5 **/
    /** Set that as IKey in Derived Table (IKey = 6)**/

Insert into Derived values(6,300,'Derived5');
    /** Find the biggest IKey in Base Table **/
    /** Set that as IKey in Derived Table (IKey = 6)**/
Insert into Derived values(6,300,'Derived6');
```

This results in the following tables:

Base

```
IKey Number Base
1   100     Base1
2   101     Base2
3   200     Base3
4   201     Base4
5   300     Base5
6   300     Base6
```

Derived

```
IKey Number Derived
1   100     Derived1
2   101     Derived2
4   200     Derived3
4   201     Derived4
6   300     Derived5
6   300     Derived6
```

I have been able to find a solution for the case#1.

```
UPDATE Derived
Set Derived.IKey = Derived.IKey - 1

FROM    Derived 
        INNER JOIN
        Base
        ON
            Derived.IKey - 1 = Base.IKey
            AND 
            Derived.Number = Base.Number

WHERE   Derived.IKey
IN
      (
              /** Query to get all records which have duplicates in a table but the previous key is not used**/
              SELECT
                Derived.IKey
              FROM
                Derived
              WHERE
                Derived.IKey - 1 NOT IN (SELECT IKey FROM Derived)
              GROUP BY 
                Derived.IKey
              HAVING 
                COUNT(Derived.IKey) > 1
       )
```

I want to find a solution for #2.

Here is a workspace set up to experiment with the problem.
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5f4e/4

Comment: if you use the `row_number() partition by ()` function then you get a number for your 'group' (identical identifier); and then you can update row #1 with the row #2 per group

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update one of 2 duplicates in an sql server database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783906/update-one-of-2-duplicates-in-an-sql-server-database-table)