# Modify record using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new with the stored procedure.

I have 4 million records so that manually cannot do that so use stored procedure.

I have a table like:

```
Id   Name
-----------------
1    abc
2    xyz
3    abc
4    pqr
5    abc
6    pqr
```

And in that table one filed is called Name. In Name column, some are record are same name so I want to modify records and want like:

```
Id   Name
---------------------
1    abc
2    xyz
3    abc-1
4    pqr
5    abc-2
6    pqr-1
```

& Insert it into another table which have same schema.

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: Ok so you want to update duplicate data and insert the data into a new table?

Comment: Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783906/update-one-of-2-duplicates-in-an-sql-server-database-table

Comment: @PKirby yes i want to update duplicate data & insert into new table.

Comment: Hi @vatsal, Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
      from onetable t
     )
update toupdate
    set name = name + '-' + cast(seqnum - 1 as varchar(255))
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Actually, that updates it in place.  To put this into another table:

```
with toinsert as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
      from onetable t
    )
select id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then name
             else name + '-' + cast(seqnum - 1 as varchar(255))
        end) as name
into newtable
from toinsert;
```

Comment: i didn't understand code can you pls decribe which is store procedure &  logic where you have write. can you simplfy it.

Comment: @vatsai . . . These are queries that do what you want.  A stored procedure is not necessary.

Comment: i have abc table which have filed name(that i explain in question) its has 10 column & i want to  insert into table name xyz which has 5 column i want to insert abc table name & id value into table xyz's table name,entityid as Id of abc. with performing same opration which explain in question. what i have to change in your query Or else can you guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This will update the table

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) AS rno,

  FROM table1
)

update t.Name = t.Name + '-'+ c.rno
from table1 t
join cte c on c.id = t.id  
where c.rno >1
```

To insert simply use select with `charindex`

```
select * into Table2 from table1
where CHARINDEX('-',name) > 1
```