# Replacing space with ? In Informatica

Tags: informatica

I have a scenario where my Data looks like below

```
COLA
'XYZ'
'XYZ  '
'ABC PQR'
'ABC PQR  '
```

There are duplicates with same name but one have Space at the ending and then '
I want those space to be Replaced by '?' . So the data would look like

```
COLA
'XYZ'
'XYZ?'
'ABC PQR'
'ABC PQR?'
```

Please help with your suggestions

Comment: If don't missunderstand you this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783906/update-one-of-2-duplicates-in-an-sql-server-database-table) will what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Harun KARATAS But I need to implement it in Informatica

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple IIF(SUBSTR (FIELD,-1) = ' ', RTRIM(FIELD) || '?', FIELD).

This assumes that even if you get multiple spaces at the end of one string you'd be happy to replace them all with just 1 ?.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another interview tricky question with no real-life application to me but...

`IIF(RTRIM(COLA)=RTRIM(prev_COLA), RTRIM(COLA) || '?', COLA)`

This assumes the data is sorted before the Expression Transformation and `prev_COLA` is a variable port having previous value of the COLA port.

Comment: Now that you mention it... it does seem like a pointless interview question