# Use group by and having count in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
select Claim_no, Count(Claim_No) Duplicate
from Claim_Report_CLP_Working
group by Claim_No
having count(*) > 1;
```

Basically, I need to update my table with a Duplicate column in which if the Claim No is more than one then the Duplicate column will return 2, 3, 4, ... based on the number of duplicates identified.

However, I need the above query to be in an UPDATE statement. I am not sure on how to do that, could someone please help me with this.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Use a _computed column_, or a trigger, to avoid data inconsistency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update one of 2 duplicates in an sql server database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783906/update-one-of-2-duplicates-in-an-sql-server-database-table)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help here.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `ROW_NUMBER` as below:

```
UPDATE A 
SET <<duplicate_column_name>> = A.Duplicate
FROM
(
    SELECT Claim_no
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Claim_No ORDER BY <<DATE_FIELD>>) Duplicate
    FROM Claim_Report_CLP_Working
) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps .

```
WITH ClaimsCTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Claim_no ORDER BY Claim_no) AS RowNum 
    FROM Claim_Report_CLP_Working
)
update ClaimsCTE 
set XXX = 'YYY' where RowNum > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *number* of duplicates, then use `count(*)` as a window function:

```
with toupdate as (
      select crcw.*, count(*) over (partition by claim_no) as new_num_duplicates
      from Claim_Report_CLP_Working crcw
     )
update toupdate
    set num_duplicates = new_num_duplicates;
```

Use `row_number()` if you want to *enumerate* the duplicate values, rather than counting all of them.

Because you are looking for the total number of duplicates (as I read the question), I would recommend including this on all rows.  Of course, you can use `where new_num_duplicates >= 2` if you only want to update rows with duplicates.

EDIT:

If you want a sequential number, then use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select crcw.*, 
             row_number(*) over (partition by claim_no order by ?) as seqnum
      from Claim_Report_CLP_Working crcw
     )
update toupdate
    set num_duplicates = seqnum;
```

The `?` is for the column used for ordering.  If you don't care, you can just use `claim_no` or `order by (select null)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. I tried this query and it returns the total number of duplicates means if a claim no is repeated 5 times. It will show the number 5 on the num_duplicates column for all rows of claim no. But, I need the num_duplicates column to return 1,2,3. For example first row identified for claim no column will return 1 on the num_duplicates and the same claim no on the other row will return 2 on the num_duplicates and so on.